# How to write content in files through Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell, and I want to read multiple files in a folder (subfolders) and want to put/write my content in the file in a specific place.
But if that content already available in the file, it should skip means not to write in a file

#### Example

I have two config files

```
C:\Projects\Project_1\project1.config
C:\Projects\Project_2\project2.config
```

project1.config file contains

```
add key="Environment" value="Dev"/
add key="Environment" value="Demo"/
```

project2.config file contains

```
add key="Environment" value="Dev"/
```

I want to write a script that both files should have below content

```
add key="Environment" value="Dev"/
add key="Environment" value="Demo"/
```

project1.config should not copy this data because it already has it, only project2.config should add this code

Comment: The trailing slash in your data suggests that your config files actually contain XML. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This might not perform well with large files but a simple approach is to read all of the files in and drop any duplicate lines.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Projects" -Recurse -Include "*.config" | 
    ForEach-Object{Get-Content $_.FullName} | 
    Select-Object -Unique | 
    Set-Content "C:\temp\NewFile.config"
```

Get all the config files that are under the Projects direcory and read each file as an array. Then use `Select-Object -Unique` to remove any duplicates from the collection of files.

Comment: Thanks Matt.. let me try this